# Add "Parts" to the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

I want to have a table of contents as follows:

```
1. Introduction

Part 1: the partition function

2. section 2

3. section 3

Part 2: theta function

4. section 4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: have you used `\part{...}` I would expect that to add to the toc automatically.

Comment: If not, use \addtocontents{toc}{Part I: the partition function\par} command.

Comment: OP wants the word `part` to appear before the part number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package to add the string "Part" to the entries in the ToC; I used

```
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
```

so the the `section` counter is reset in each new part and the `part` counter uses Arabic numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftpartpresnum\cftpartaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftpartnumwidth{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\part{First test part}
\section{Test section}
\section{Test section}
\part{Second  test part}
\section{Test section}
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you make the `\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}` work in the `book` class?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\newcommand{\atoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1\par}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\atoc{Part 1: the partition function}

\section{section 2}

\section{section 3}

\atoc{Part 2: theta function}

\section{section 4}

\end{document}
```

an image is attached
[image]

Comment: While a workable solution, I would caution against using it as-is.  Consider the following: it is possible (read *likely*) that you will want to change the style of how the parts appear in the table of contents when you are finished.  This solution, as is, has you re-specifying every single `addtocontents` line to match the new format---a monotonous and error prone task.  It would be better to place the line inside a `newcommand` that *abstracts* the idea of adding a TOC entry for the part.

Comment: @Sean Points well taken. Something like \newcommand{\atoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1\par}} and \atoc{Part 1: the partition function}. Appreciated.