# Adding the string "part" before the entries in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, parts

I want to add the word "Part" before my entries in the toc.

I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129592/add-parts-to-the-table-of-contents) that I could use \renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}. I have tried adding making some modifications to the partpresnum and partleader command but it did not work.

I am using the classicthesis style, which defines the toc like this for parts: 
(The full style file can be seen [here](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty))

```
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@parts}}%
    {%
      \renewcommand{\thepart}{\roman{part}}%
      \renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\scshape}%  \MakeTextLowercase
%      \renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{\cftchapaftersnum}%
%      \renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\quad}%
%      \setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\cftpartnumwidth}
      \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\color{Maroon}\normalfont}%
      \renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalfont}%
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
      {%
        \renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}% 
        \renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%
      }%        
      \setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1em}%
      \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1em}%
      \setlength{\beforebibskip}{\cftbeforepartskip}%
     }{\relax}
    % chapters
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\relax}%
        {%
            \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}%
            \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}%
            \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}%
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{@dottedtoc}}{\relax}%
                {%
                \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\hspace{1.5em}}% 
                \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}% 
            }
            %\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1em}%           
        }
```

... see style file for full code.

Any suggestions? Am I trying to make changes in the right place even?

The following is a reduced example. I tried using only a portion of the style file, but I couldn't get that working.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{First test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\part{Second  test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As such, your example is something 'cut out' and users have to apply their chrystal ball in order to guess what comes before and after it ;-)

Comment: I have added a reduced example. You do need the external style file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `classicthesis` uses the `tocloft` package internally to generate the ToC, adding a "Part~" string can be achieved with the following code (assuming that your LaTeX installation has the latest version of the `tocloft` package):

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Part~}

\newlength{\mylen} % a "scratch" length
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftpartpresnum} % extra space
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\mylen} % add the extra space
```

Notice that by redefining the `\cftpartpresnum` command to prepend the "Part~" string, we are adding text to the number box in addition to the part number. Thus, we need to increase the width of the box to include the additional text. One possible method is to create a new length that will store the width of the additional text and add the extra space to the `\cftpartnumwidth` macro.

[image]

**EDIT:** I'm adding the full code (based on the provided MWE) that produces the desired results. In addition, the `tocloft` package I used (v2.3f, 2013/05/02) is downloaded from [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Part~}

\newlength{\mylen} % a "scratch" length
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftpartpresnum} % extra space
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\mylen} % add the extra space

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{First test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\part{Second  test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE:** For earlier versions of the `tocloft` package the documentation states that using it together with the KOMA classes (and others) might result in `\cftpartpresnum` becoming doubled in the output. This behavior is fixed (at least) since version 2.3f.

**EDIT 2:** Passing the `parts` option to the `classicthesis` package seems to disable this workaround. The reason is that, when using this option, the `classicthesis` class relies on the `titlesec` package in order to produce the ToC entry for parts. Luckily, the documentation for the package states that:

> - `\part` does not encapsulates the label in the toc entry, except if you
>     use the `newparttoc` option. [page 10]

and the description for the option itself further adds:

> Standard parts write the toc entry number in a non standard way. You
>   may change that with `newparttoc` so that `titletoc` or a similar package
>   can manipulate the entry. (That works only if `\part` has been
>   redefined.) [page 8]

Thus, to get the desired behavior, it's simply a matter of passing this option to the `titlesec` package with `\PassOptionsToPackage{newparttoc}{titlesec}`, prior to loading the `classicthesis` package.

The final code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\PassOptionsToPackage{newparttoc}{titlesec} % MUST be called before classicthesis
\usepackage[dottedtoc,floatperchapter,parts]{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Part~}

\newlength{\mylen} % a "scratch" length
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftpartpresnum} % extra space
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\mylen} % add the extra space

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{First test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\part{Second  test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

and the output produced:
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it does not do anything. Could it be because of the version issue?

Comment: I have version 2013.72.2.3fsvn30209-11.2.1

Comment: @dorien It works fine for me with the latest `tocloft` package (version 2.3f). What do you mean with "it does not do anything?"

Comment: The toc is still the same. Could it be that the template is overwriting it?

Comment: I updated the answer with a full MWE that gives the desired results (on my installation). Can you check if this works on your installation? Also, can you double-check that the `tocloft` package you're using is the same as the one in the link I provided?

Comment: Thank you. The problem seems to be because I load classicthesis with: \usepackage[dottedtoc,floatperchapter,parts]{classicthesis}. Especially the parts option does this. I do need it however for the nice parts layout. So I'm guessing I need to change something in the classicthesis style.

Comment: There's no need to tinker with the `classicthesis` style. I updated the answer to include a workaround for the `parts` option. This will hopefully fulfill your requirements :)

Comment: Getting closer. This works on the template, but on my full document the main memory is exceeded. I've already expanded the memory, but it keeps exceeding it. Strange.

Comment: It would appear that this in my preamble is producing the error:\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=FitV, breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,% plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1, hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O, urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, }

Comment: More specifically, the bookmarksnumbered seems to be causing an incompatibility. Perhaps I can just do without this option. Let me check! That would be awesome :)