# Redefining "part" style

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, article

I would like to redefine part style with LuaLatex:
(I have checked other answers here like this but it doesn't seem to fit my questions quite well: [add parts to toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129592/add-parts-to-the-table-of-contents)

- can I optimize by redefining the "part" style globally so it will always be on a separate page preferably with 1/3 space above and 2/3 space below? (Also probably having it a bit more indented to the right would be prettier for the eye, but my attempts to use \hspace{...cm} failed)
- it would be really ideal if the size of "Teil I" would match the one in the part title itself

Thank you very much!

[image: MWE result]

That's my MWE

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  parskip,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage{hyphenat}% create hypen without overfull box

\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}% correct TOC count for tableshttps://www.overleaf.com/project/6306f7ae98db98de7e4c0e98
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
%\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}}}% TOC in bookmarks

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\part{Theory}
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\clearpage
\section{Theory I}
\section{Theory II}
blabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, the question is about scrartcl.

Comment: Use `\setkomafont{partprefix}{\usekomafont{part}}` to get the same font for part prefix and part heading text.

Comment: @esdd thank you that worked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hook mechanism of `scrartcl`.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  parskip,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  footskip=1cm,
  showframe,% remove in production version
]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%\usepackage{hyphenat}% create hypen without overfull box

\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
%\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}}}% TOC in bookmarks

\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/part}{\clearpage\vspace*{\stretch{1}}}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/part}{\vspace*{\stretch{2}}\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Theory}

\section{Theory I}
\section{Theory II}

blabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the `\stretch` factors to suit your taste.

Comment: perfect, thank you!